# Add rows and columns to pandas dataframe based on a given list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like this:

```
frame = pd.DataFrame(
    [[pd.Timestamp('2014-01-01'), pd.Timestamp('2014-01-02')]],
    columns=("date", "timestamp"),
)

>>> frame
       date  timestamp
0 2014-01-01 2014-01-02
```

I also have a list of values like this - note the numpy NaN as the second value:

```
vals = [1, np.NaN]
```

I would like to end up with a dataframe, `new_frame`, where the rows from `frame` are repeated as many times as there are items in `vals`, and I would like to add a `val` column to `frame` where the values in each row correspond to the values from the list `vals`. It should look like this:

```
       date  timestamp  val
0 2014-01-01 2014-01-02    1
1 2014-01-01 2014-01-02    NaN
```

Currently I am doing it this way:

```
new_frame = pd.concat([frame]*len(vals))
new_frame = new_frame.set_index([list(range(0, len(vals)))])
new_frame['value'] = pd.Series(vals)
```

I am wondering, is there a more concise way to do this, perhaps using some built-in functionality in pandas?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
frame2 = pd.DataFrame([frame.ix[0]]*len(vals))
frame2.index = range(len(vals))
frame2['val'] = vals
```

This creates a data frame by repeating the first row of your existing frame, then adds the column `val`.

If you can afford to do it while creating the data frame `frame`, you can do:

```
frame = pd.DataFrame(
    [[pd.Timestamp('2014-01-01'), pd.Timestamp('2014-01-02')] for x in vals],
    columns=("date", "timestamp"),
)
frame['val'] = vals
```

This creates a data frame with the right number of rows, then adds the column `val`.

Comment: This method results in an incorrect index  - I would need to set it anyway - so it's basically the same as what I'm doing above. The dataframe is created earlier and the list changes dynamically in a function, so I can't do it while creating the dataframe.

Comment: True. I added a line to reset the index. let me know if that works for you.

Comment: This definitely works, but I'm looking for something more concise, preferably some single pandas function that can do this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) and [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) with columns `date` and `timestamp` by method `ffill` - forward filling `NaN` values:

```
print frame
#        date  timestamp
#0 2014-01-01 2014-01-02

vals = [1, np.NaN, 2, np.nan]
print vals
#[1, nan, 2, nan]

df = pd.concat([frame, pd.Series(vals, name='value')], axis=1)
df[['date','timestamp']] = df[['date','timestamp']].fillna(method='ffill')
print df
#        date  timestamp  value
#0 2014-01-01 2014-01-02      1
#1 2014-01-01 2014-01-02    NaN
#2 2014-01-01 2014-01-02      2
#3 2014-01-01 2014-01-02    NaN
```

Or use `ffill`:

```
print frame
#        date  timestamp
#0 2014-01-01 2014-01-02

vals = [1, np.NaN, 2, np.nan]
print vals
#[1, nan, 2, nan]

df = pd.concat([frame, pd.Series(vals, name='value')], axis=1)
df[['date','timestamp']] = df[['date','timestamp']].ffill()
print df
#        date  timestamp  value
#0 2014-01-01 2014-01-02      1
#1 2014-01-01 2014-01-02    NaN
#2 2014-01-01 2014-01-02      2
#3 2014-01-01 2014-01-02    NaN
```